# extract two elements float[] at a time

Tags: c#

I have an array float[ ] that contains 50 elements, the dataset looks similar to

```
 -15.489830  13.296105  -15.489830  -0.350000  -15.489830  -4.432035  -11.617373  -6.648053  11.617373  -2.216017  -11.617373  2.216017  -11.617373  6.648053  -11.617373  11.080088
1.630000  0.100000  2.900000..etc
```

I would like to read two elements at a time so desired output looks like this

```
-15.489830,13.296105
-15.489830,-0.350000
-15.489830,-4.432035

..etc
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
float[] dataArray = new float[]
{
    -15.489830, 13.296105, -15.489830, -0.350000, -15.489830, -4.432035, -11.617373, -6.648053, 11.617373, -2.216017,
    -11.617373, 2.216017, -11.617373, 6.648053, -11.617373, 11.080088, 1.630000, 0.100000, 2.900000
};

for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.Length; i += 2)
{
    float firstValue = dataArray[i];
    float secondValue = dataArray[i + 1];
    Console.WriteLine($"{firstValue},{secondValue}");
}
```

Comment: awesome!! exactly what I needed.  Many thanks Basil..